# How can I show multiple event values in a Deneb (vega-lite) PowerBI tooltip?

Tags: powerbi, tooltip, vega-lite, deneb, milestone

In PowerBI using a Deneb (vega-lite) visual, I have created a horizontal timeline (similar to a Gantt chart, but all along one timeline), with point marks along the timeline whenever an event occurred. Some dates have multiple events, but I can only get the point mark's tooltip to show one event. Is there a way for the tooltip to show multiple values (events) from the same field (date field) by hovering over a single point mark (point on timeline)?

I'm not sure if there is a way to group the events by date so that by hovering over a date point, multiple events would be visible in the tooltip.

Comment: Here is a sample of code for reference:"
{
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"tooltip": "true",
},
"encoding": "x": {
"field": "DueDate",
"type": "temporal"},
"tooltip": [{"field": "Event"}],
}


This successfully puts a point on each due date and when you hover, the tooltip shows the name of the event on that date, however, if a date has more than one event, the tooltip still only shows one event.

Data includes one row for each event and columns for DueDate and Event (many other columns, but for simplicities sake, I'm focusing on those two.)

Comment: Hi Caitlin, Can you prepare a simple example on vega-lite editor so we can do some tests:  https://vega.github.io/editor/#/

Comment: Please update your question with a full spec to debug.

Comment: The data and code is on a work computer, so I can try to recreate dummy data/code to share later, but I think my issue is that I want multiple rows of values to appear in the tooltip for the same field/column. If I hover over a point in the data, I want the tooltip to show multiple row values (events) if they occurred on that date. The underylying data has a column for event and date, so multiple rows could have the same date, but the event value would be different. In that case, I want the tooltip to show each row value (event), but it seems to only be able to show one row in the tooltip.

Comment: Setup a simple “page” tooltip in Power BI and that will override the deneb tooltip. There you can list all your events in a table for example. Reach out if you need some assistance setting it up.

Comment: I have a page tooltip that I've been trying to use. When I add it to built in PowerBI visuals, it shows multiple rows in the table in the tooltip, but when I add it to the deneb visual, it still only shows one row in the table.

Comment: Sounds like you need to remove the event data from your deneb chart then. Add a measure instead.